# Need to replace a hex value that is longer than the original

Tags: string, replace, hex, hex-editors

I need to change the firmware version number of a router update package.
This is what the original one looks like: https://pasteboard.co/HiA4BgH.png

I need to change it to "V200R001B270D10SP03C182" which is one character longer than the original "V200R001B180D20SP00C00"

If I paste the the new string in, it pushes everything else forward by one step. It looks like this. https://pasteboard.co/HiA5hx5.png

Should I delete one "00" behind it to make it even? And is it even possible to do this in these circumstances?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: If the buffer allocated for the version string is fixed length and one or more of the following 00's are part of the buffer then it should be safe to delete one of them. But, it is possible there is a checksum in the package and editing the version may cause it not to verify.

Comment: @JimRhodes That's great! I read the firmware only checks for the filesize which should work with that perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Do a search on "Modifying Huawei B593u firmware images using FMK". Looks like there is a tool for changing version string.

Comment: @JimRhodes seems so. Maybe it's more reliable and less "brick inducing" than the hex editor. Time to boot my Ubuntu up then. Thanks for the recomendation!